# How can I set ComboBox DataContext in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to understand Binding so I have come up with a very simple program to try and test it.

I have the following element in my MainWindow:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

In my Code I have the following observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

I can successfully add items this way at any point during runtime:

```
comboBox1.DataContext = ComboItems;
ComboItems.Clea();
ComboItems.Add("Item");
```

My question is, how could I set the DataContext in XAML so that I don't have to do it in code?  Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something common is:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" .../>
```

However usually you want to inject another object instance as `DataContext`, have a look at the MVVM pattern for example. Properties in WPF are [inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx), so the `ComboBox` has the `DataContext` of the `Window`, it can be overwritten at any level though.

Note: For the Binding to work `ComboItems` needs to be a public property, not a field.

Resources of interest:

- [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
- [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)
- [Depedency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)

Comment: One questions on the last part.  I changed ComboItems to ObservableCollection<String> { get; set; }.  I believe that is what you meant by public property, however, this gives me an 'Object reference not set...' error.

Comment: @B-Rad: Did you access it without setting a value first? (Also you should usually make the property get-only for collections, backed by a readonly field. i.e. `private readonly OC<Type> field = new OC<Type>(); public OC<Type> Property { get { return field; } }`)

Comment: @B-Rad: Also please read the data binding overview, thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and the links.  It worked great and I learned a lot!